# Идентификация пользователя по голосу

Tags: c#

Недавно дали задание для курсовой, распознавание диктора по голосу (диктор может говорить разные слова). Ну чтобы мне было легче, преподаватель дал две статьи с Хабра

https://habr.com/ru/post/144491/

https://habr.com/ru/post/144580/

До этого вроде не пользовался гитхабом, но попросили выложить код туда.

https://github.com/Sweet-heart-bakho/Cursed

И казалось вот целые две статьи, но проблем в том что мне реально они не понятны, причем один сначала делает Фурье потом оконную функцию, а другой оконную потом Фурье. И вот уже какой день пишу код результата ноль. С некоторым вроде работает, а с некоторыми нет. Правильно ли я понимаю следующие действия:

1. Извлечение данных из wav файла

```
        double[] data = readAmplitudeValues(true);
    
        double[] readAmplitudeValues(bool isBigEndian)      //перевод байтов в 16 биты
        {
            int MSB, LSB; // старший и младший байты
            byte[] buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(outfile); // читаем данные откуда-нибудь
            double[] data = new double[buffer.Length / 2];
    
            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i += 2)
            {
                if (isBigEndian) // задает порядок байтов во входном сигнале
                {
                    // первым байтом будет MSB
                    MSB = buffer[2 * i];
                    // вторым байтом будет LSB
                    LSB = buffer[2 * i + 1];
                }
                else
                {
                    // наоборот
                    LSB = buffer[2 * i];
                    MSB = buffer[2 * i + 1];
                }
                // склеиваем два байта, чтобы получить 16-битное вещественное число
                // все значения делятся на максимально возможное - 2^15
                data[i] = ((MSB << 8) | LSB);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
                data[i] = data[i];
            return data;
        }
    
    
        List<double> datalist = new List<double>();
        for (int i = 1000; i < data.Length; i++)
            datalist.Add(data[i] / 32768.0);
```

Деление на 32768 обусловленно для нормализации кажется, но везде видел что точно необходимо, почему пропускаю первые 1000 битов? Потому что обычно информация самого файла и тишини вполне.

2. Далее идет фильтрация взял из второй статьи

```
        datalist = Filtr(datalist);
        List<double> Filtr (List<double> datalist)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < datalist.Count; i++)
                 datalist[i] = (datalist[i] - (0.9 * datalist[i - 1])) * (0.54 - 0.46 * Math.Cos((i - 6)*(2 * Math.PI / 180)));
        datalist.RemoveAt(0);
        return datalist;
    }
```

3. Так как следующие действия разные в обоих статьях, я решил следующие действие будет функция Фурье

```
    int start = -4000;
    int end = 0;
    List<double> arr = new List<double>();
    for (int i = 0; i < datalist.Count; i++)
    {
        start += 4000;
        end += 4000;
        if (end > datalist.Count)
        {
            arr.Add(Furie(datalist, start, datalist.Count, i, datalist.Count - start));
            break;
        }
        arr.Add(Furie(datalist, start, end, i, end - start));
    }

    double Furie(List<double> slices, int start, int end, int f, int fr)                        //преобразование Фурье
    {
        double temp = 0.0;
        for (int t = start; t < end; t++)
        {
            temp += (slices[t] * Math.Cos((2 * Math.PI * t * f) / fr) - slices[t] * Math.Sin((2 * Math.PI * t * f) / fr));
        }
        return temp;
    }
```

Почему 4000? Ну видимо потому там просилась порезка кадров, о ней говорилось в 1 статье, но тут тоже самое, тем более как мне понять сколько битов в 128мс.
3. Далее оконная функция Hemming, так как С Кайзером я так и не понял.

```
    datalist = Hemming(datalist);

    List<double> Hemming(List<double> slices)                       //окно Хемминга для устранения нежелательных эффектов
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < slices.Count; i++)
            slices[i] = 0.53836 - (0.46164 * Math.Cos((Math.PI * 2 * slices[i]) / (slices.Count - 1)));
        return slices;
    }
```

4. И на последок переход к мел шкале, в которой требуется от нас Гц в то время как у меня амплитуды, где взять герцы? И что с ними потом делать?
5. Сравнение я уже взял из 2 статьи так как Коррелляция Пирсона явно лучше, так как получаем значение от 0 до 1. Хотя бы это я смог реализовать.

Дополняю, пробовал способ извлечения данных из .wav с помощью библиотеки NAudio

```
    double[] data;
    using (WaveFileReader reader = new WaveFileReader(outfile))
    {
        byte[] bytesBuffer = new byte[reader.Length];
        int read = reader.Read(bytesBuffer, 0, bytesBuffer.Length);
        double[] floatSamples = new double[read / 2];
        for (int sampleIndex = 0; sampleIndex < read / 2; sampleIndex++)
        {
            var intSampleValue = BitConverter.ToInt16(bytesBuffer, sampleIndex * 2);
            floatSamples[sampleIndex] = intSampleValue / 32768.0;
        }
        data = floatSamples;
    }
```

Кстати данные вообще разные на выход

Для меня эти две статьи все еще остаются не понятыми. Надеюсь на вашу помощь.

**Дополнение от 15.12.2021**

Так как мне не совсем понятна функция Фурье в данной программе, а именно момент с окном (нужно самому выбрать размер вашего окна), я начал проводить тесты с разменом окна и вы удивитесь но от размера окна результат всегда разный причём порой меняется кардинально. Скоро скину результаты прогонов.

P.S. по первым прогонам можно точно сказать +- хорошие резултаты выходят при окне от 17000 и выше. В разных источников писались разные оконные промежутки, но проблема в том что там описывается время (20мс - 40мс), а у нас 16-биты. Я пробовал уже узнать количество переменных в 40мс файле, около 36000.

**Дополнение от 16.12.2021**

Входе тестов выявил следующие размеры что дают +- нужный результат, конечно среди них можно все еще выявить лучшие. Там просто случайный набор чисел, не уверен что хотя бы один из чисел имеет смысл.

**Дополнение от 20.12.2021**

У файлов wav оказывается есть битрейт и держу пари что оно влияет на выходные данные так что перед тем как сверять амплитуды, стоит изменить бирейт всех на файлов 8000, 16, 1 (гц, бирейт, моно)
Ниже код это испралвяет не забываем библиотеку NAudio

```
using (var reader = new WaveFileReader("input.wav"))
{
    var newFormat = new WaveFormat(8000, 16, 1); 
    using (var conversionStream = new WaveFormatConversionStream(newFormat, reader))
    {
        WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile("output.wav", conversionStream);
    } 
}
```

Для проверки битрейта файла

```
    int bitrate;
    using (var f = File.OpenRead(outfile))
    {
        f.Seek(28, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        byte[] val = new byte[4];
        f.Read(val, 0, 4);
        bitrate = BitConverter.ToInt32(val, 0);
    }
```

Comment: При надобоности могу скинуть текстом все мои версии кода, которые работают (не так как надо). Есть хорошая база голосовых.

Comment: Если работа со звуком, попробуйте использовать библиотеку NAudio. Большинство рутины по работе со звуком она сделает за вас.

Comment: Преподаватель требует использовать математику и логику. И скептически относится к посторонним библиотекам. Использую ее чтобы переводить файлы из .m4a в .wav

Comment: А, это учебное задание, тогда понятно, не сразу заметил. Но NAudio - не просто посторонняя библиотека, а самая популярная и правильная библиотека, на которой работает куча приложений под .NET.

Comment: @aepot Понятное дело я даже пробовал способ извлечения данных из файла с помощью этой библоитеки

Comment: С WAV файлами не все так гладко как кажется. Там каналы могут быть по-разному записаны. Я бы посоветовал сначала использовать библиотечную реализацию при работе с файлами, а уже потом, если потребуется, написать свою. Как я понял, суть вашего задания не в том чтобы грамотно распарсить WAV файл. По самому заданию не подскажу, надо долго сидеть вникать, уж простите. Могу еще совет не в тему дать - вот такая штука есть [BinaryPrimitives](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.buffers.binary.binaryprimitives?view=net-5.0), актуальная замена BitConverter, может помочь сделать код проще.

Comment: Во всяком случае, у вас параметры PCM и количество каналов может быть разное в разных файлах. С помощью библиотеки, вы можете легко сделать ресемпл звука в какой-то свой стандарт, чтобы потом сравнивать получившееся правильно. Конечно, если все файлы записаны строго в одной конфигурации записи, то это неактуально.

Comment: @aepot Я правильно понял что есть проблема на каком устройсвте был записан звук? Если так то плохо все, значит надо еще решить проблему изъятия данных из файла

Comment: `Кстати данные вообще разные на выход` значит у вас есть баги при декодировании WAV файла. :) это ж очевидно. `значит надо еще решить проблему изъятия данных из файла` - именно с этого и стоит начать - быть на 100% уверенным, что файл считан всегда правильно.

Comment: @aepot делал все как по статье на Хабре, ох уж эти статьи ничем не подкрепленные

Comment: Прочитал тут Вашу переписку... Я правильно понимаю, что гланая часть алгоитма звучит так: "получить спектры голосов из двух файлов. Сравнить. Если спектры существенно различаются - это разные дикторы"?

Comment: @S.H. именно, насчет различия спектров уже мы сами решаем, но думаю на уровне 80%.

Comment: Решил помочь с вопросом назначив за ответ награду) Удачки с решением проблемы)

Comment: советую выложить свои наработки в общий доступ на гитхабе и оставить ссылочку в начале вопроса

Comment: @Andrew приложил ссылку на гитхаб с кодом, который как да и работает, но не уверен, есть минус его, это должен быть хороший микрофон

Comment: Залей код всего проекта. Что бы человек желающий тебе помочь просто скачал проэкт и просто запустил. И научись пользоваться git-ом - это ***критически*** важная часть работы программиста (им и заливай на гитхаб). (это не претензии, это настоятельная рекомендация)

Comment: @Andrew мой код написан на .net 6, если у вас такой же, то все сработает, берет он аудио файлы из вашей папки в документах "Аудиозаписи", конечно елси у вас windows. Введите название файлов и все код все сделает.

Comment: На будущее - если хочешь сделать большими шансы того что тебе помогут - сделай так что бы помогающие люди потратили минимум времени на это)  Я не в курсе про все виды проэктов на шарпе, но вот, например, обычно консольные программы имеют метод main(args) который является стартовой точкой. У твоего кода я такой стартовой точки не вижу, тогда выходит что это не стандартная консольная программа и не винформс проэкт, а какой-то иной вид проэкта или же что ты кинул не полный код. В любом случае - постарайся помочь людям помочь тебе) Тогда и ты с большей вероятностью получишь желаемую помощь)

Comment: И даже если представить что этот вид проэкта имеет иную стартовую точку - то человеку все равно прийдется мало того что догадатся что это за вид проэкта, так еще и вручную настраивать зависимости и nu-package-ы(А у тебя там как минимум NAudio). Что тоже трата времени другого человека попусту. Вобщем - не поленись и залей нормально весь проэкт.

Comment: @Andrew как я и сказал проект на .net 6 там стартовая точка не обязательна, проект идет сверху вниз. Насчет package NAudio. Возможно и правда стоило добавить туда

Comment: ссылка на github битая

Comment: было бы неплохо добавить звуковые файлы тоже в проект

Comment: @Grundy проверил ссылку на другом устройсвте вроде все нормально, да у меня тут многослойная программа если кидать то все, но мне осталось лишь доделать UI UX и скину всю прогу в гитхаб, с некоторыми семплами

Comment: Выложил ГИТ с готовый кодом (ну как готовым) там 3 слойное приложениес UI Data Buisness
база данных пуста можете свое как всегда добавить)))